# Accumulated Frequencies, Ngrams

Tags: python, regex, nltk

quick question here: if you run the code below you get a list of frequencies of bigrams per list from the corpus.

I would like to be able to display and keep track of a total running tally. IE instead of what you see displayed when you run it as 1 or maybe 2 for the frequency because the index is so small, it counts through the whole corpus and displays frequencies.

I then basically need to generate text from the frequencies that models the original corpus.

```
   #---------------------------------------------------------
#!/usr/bin/env python
#Ngram Project

#Import all of the libraries we will need for the program to function
import nltk
import nltk.collocations
from collections import defaultdict
import nltk.corpus as corpus
from nltk.corpus import brown

#---------------------------------------------------------

#create our list with the Brown corpus inside variable called "news"
news = corpus.brown.sents(categories = 'editorial')
#This will display the type of variable Python recognizes this as
print "News Is Of The Variable Type : ",type(news),'\n'

#---------------------------------------------------------


#This function will take in the corpus one line at a time
#After searching through and adding a <s> to the beggning of each list item, it also annotates periods out for </s>'
def alter_list(corpus_list):
    #Simply check for an instance of a period, and if so, replace with '</s>'
    if corpus_list[-1] == '.':
        corpus_list[-1] = '</s>'
        #Stripe is a modifier that allows us to remove all special characters, IE '\n'
        corpus_list[-1].strip()
    #Else add to the end of the list item
    else:
        corpus_list.append('</s>')
    return ['<s>'] + corpus_list

#Displays the length of the list 'news'
print "The Length of News is : ",len(news),'\n'
#Allows the user to choose how much of the annotated corpus they would like to see
print "How many lines of the <s> // </s> annotated corpus would you like to see? ", '\n'
user = input()
#Takes user input to determine how many lines to display if any
if(user >= 1):
    print "The Corpus Annotated with <s> and </s> looks like : "
    print "Displaying [",user,"] rows of the corpus : ", '\n' 
    for corpus_list in news[:user]:
       print(alter_list(corpus_list),'\n')
#Non positive number catch
else:
    print "Fine I Won't Show You Any... ",'\n'

#---------------------------------------------------------

print '\n'
#Again allows the user to choose the number of lists from Brown corpus to be displayed in
# Unigram, bigram, trigram and quadgram format
user2 = input("How many list sequences would you like to see broken into bigrams, trigrams, and quadgrams? ")
count = 0

#Function 'ngrams' is run in a loop so that each entry in the list can be gone through and turned into information
#Displayed to the user
while(count < user2):
    passer = news[count]

    def ngrams(passer, n = 2, padding = True):
        #Padding refers to the same idea demonstrated above, that is bump the first word to the second, making
        #'None' the first item in each list so that calculations of frequencies can be made 
        pad = [] if not padding else [None]*(n-1)
        grams = pad + passer + pad
        return (tuple(grams[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(grams) - (n - 1)))

    #In this case, arguments are first: n-gram type (bi, tri, quad)
    #Followed by in our case the addition of 'padding'
    #Padding is used in every case here because we need it for calculations
    #This function structure allows us to pull in corpus parts without the added annotations if need be
    for size, padding in ((1,1), (2,1), (3, 1), (4, 1)):
        print '\n%d - grams || padding = %d' % (size, padding)
        print list(ngrams(passer, size, padding))

    # show frequency
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for n_gram in ngrams(passer, 2, False):
        counts[n_gram] += 1

    print ("======================================================================================")
    print '\nFrequencies Of Bigrams:'
    for c, n_gram in sorted(((c, n_gram) for n_gram, c in counts.iteritems()), reverse = True):
        print c, n_gram

    print '\nFrequencies Of Trigrams:'
    for c, n_gram in sorted(((c, n_gram) for n_gram, c in counts.iteritems()), reverse = True):
        print c, n_gram

    count = count + 1

 #---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question. nltk has a function generate. The book from which nltk comes from is available online.

http://nltk.org/book/ch01.html

```
Now, just for fun, let's try generating some random text in the various styles we have just seen. To do this, we type the name of the text followed by the term generate. (We need to include the parentheses, but there's nothing that goes between them.)

>>> text3.generate()
In the beginning of his brother is a hairy man , whose top may reach
unto heaven ; and ye shall sow the land of Egypt there was no bread in
all that he was taken out of the month , upon the earth . So shall thy
wages be ? And they made their father ; and Isaac was old , and kissed
him : and Laban with his cattle in the midst of the hands of Esau thy
first born , and Phichol the chief butler unto his son Isaac , she
```

Comment: Sorry I mean, take bigrams, trigrams and quad grams, then calculate their probabilities, then use that to generate manually corpus like text.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you define the dict `counts` anew for each sentence, so the ngram counts get reset to zero. Define it above the while loop and the counts will accumulate over the entire Brown corpus.

Bonus advice: You should also move the definition of `ngram` outside the loop-- it's nonsensical to define the same function over and over and over. (But it does no harm, except to performance). Better yet, you should use the nltk's `ngram` function and read about `FreqDist`, which is like a dict counter on steroids. It will come in handy when you tackle the statistical text generation.